# Compare two objects in vector iteration C++

Tags: c++, vector, comparison-operators

How to implement the comparison function in this case?

```
void remove(const Object1 &object1) {
    for(auto &object2 : objectVector) {
        if(object1 == object2) {
            /*....... */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean how to erase the element of a vector? Or do you not know how to implement `operator==` for the `Object` class?

Comment: I basically want to remove the given element from the list and I think this is a way of doing it right?

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that if you `erase` an element in a range based `for` loop, you must `break` as `std::vector::erase` invalidates iterators.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking 2 questions:

1. How can objects be made comparable:

By implementing `operator==` for the class. Be sure you override `operator !=` then too.

As a member function:

```
bool Object1::operator ==(const Object1 &b) const
{
    // return true if *this equals b;
}
```

Or as a free function:

```
bool operator ==(const Object1 &a, const Object1 &b)
```

2. How can objects with a given value be removed from a vector:

The easiest way is to use `std::remove`:

```
objectVector.erase(std::remove(objectVector.begin(), objectVector.end(), object1), objectVector.end());
```

You can remove objects also while iterating through the vector, but you have to keep in mind that the vector iterator is invalidated then. You may not further iterate on the vector then.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to implement the comparison function as a non-member function to allow implicit type conversions on both sides.

Comment: `return true if *this equals b;` At least comment it out.

Comment: "It should be default-implemented in most-cases." not really no

Comment: There's no remove function in std which takes these arguments.

Comment: There is. Look at the first overload here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove

Answer (score 0):

if object is a class you can override the operator == in the class as a friend function, or you can implement your own function bool isEqual(Object1 o1, Object1 o2) { if(something) return true; return false; }

Answer (score 0):

An object of your class can contain different types and number of members so let's say that you have a class `A`:

```
class A{
    int x,
    float y;
    char* z;
};
```

And you have two instances:

```
A a1;
A a2;
```

To compare:

```
if(a1 == a2) // compile-time error
    ;// DoSomeThing
```

Above you get the error because the compiler doesn't know which fields will be compared against each other. The solution is to overload the equals operator "==" to work on objects of your class.

```
class Student{
    public:
        Student(std::string, int age);
        std::string getName()const;
        int getAge()const;

        bool operator == (const Student&);
    private:
        std::string name;
        int age;
};

Student::Student(std::string str, int x) : 
    name(str), age(x){
}

bool Student::operator == (const Student& rhs){
    return age == rhs.age;  
}

std::string Student::getName()const{
    return name;
}

int Student::getAge()const{
    return age;
}


int main(){


    Student a("Alpha", 77);
    Student b("Beta", 49);

    if(a == b)
        std::cout << a.getName() << " is the same age as " << 
        b.getName() << std::endl;


    cout << endl << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

- Now the compiler knows how to compare objects of your class and know what the equals operator compares on your ojects members.